# Why $(x)$ is a prime non-maximal ideal in $K[x,y]$ where $K$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The ring of poynomials $K[x,y]$, $K$ a field is not a principal ideal domain. I want to show that in this ring non-zero prime ideals need not be maximal.

I am having difficulties in showing that $(x)$ is prime but it is not maximal.

Let $f(x)$, $g(x)$ be two elements of $K[x,y]$ such that $f(x)g(x)$ is in $(x)$. Then there exists $h(x)$ in $K[x,y]$ such that $f(x)g(x)=xh(x)$. So, $x$ divides the product $f(x)g(x)$.

How can I arrive in the conclusion that either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is in $(x)$?

Would you help me, please?

Comment: The title makes no sense -- clearly, $\left(x\right)$ is a principal ideal! To check that $\left(x\right)$ is prime, recall that an ideal is prime if and only if the quotient ring modulo this ideal is an integral domain.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for your answer. So, you mean that $K[x,y]/(x)$ is  an integral domain and hence $(x)4 is prime.

Comment: What difficulties, exactly, about showing what **you** have been asked to show?  Please include your efforts and thoughts on the problem (other than "I am having difficulties"  (with *what*, specifically).... Otherwise, this looks like a "do it for me" post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ring homomorphism $K[x,y] \to K[y], f(x,y) \mapsto f(0,y)$ induces an isomorphism $K[x,y]/(x) \cong K[y]$. Now $K[y]$ is a domain, but not a field, thus $(x)$ is prime, but not maximal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot prove why $K[y]$ is not a field. Polynomials of degree zero, so non-zero constants have an inverse since $K$ is a field. But, why every non-zero element of $K[x,y]$ does not have an inverse? :(

Comment: If $f \in K[y]$ has degree $d>1$, then what can be said about the degree of $f \cdot g$ for any nonzero $g \in K[y]$? What is the degree of $1 \in K[y]$?

Comment: User1999  Take some time to work with hints and others' help before trying to squeeze as much of an answer ("all steps please") you can get without trying yourself, to begin with.

Comment: @Jack Thank you! Now, I can see it. If $f(x)$ is a non-zero polynomial which has an inverse, then there would exists a non-zero polynomial $g(x)$ such that $f(x)g(x)$=$1$. But $deg(f(x)g(x))=deg(f(x))+deg(g(x))$ it is diffrent from zero contrary to the fact that $deg(1)$ is zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Compare the *residues*  $K[x,y]/I$ of the ideals $I$ in the chain below.

$\begin{align} 
\color{#b0f}{(x)}&\subseteq \, (x,y)\subseteq (1)\quad\ \rm [ideals]\\[.3em]
\color{#b0f}{K[y]} &\supset \ \ \ K\   \,\supset\  (0)\quad\ \rm [residues]\\[.5em]
{\rm Hence}\ \
 K[x,y]/(x)=\color{#b0f}{K[y]}&{\rm\,\ is\ a\ \ \color{#c00}{nonfield}\ \ \color{#0a0}{domain}}\\[.3em]
\Rightarrow\ \color{#b0f}{(x)}&{\rm\,\ is\ a\ \color{#c00}{nonmaximal}\ \color{#0a0}{prime}}\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

In a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344010/why-x-is-a-prime-non-maximal-ideal-in-kx-y-where-k-is-a-field/2344101#comment4826417_2344023) you wrote that you seek a direct proof, not using quotient rings. Below is one.

If $D$ is ring and $f\in D[x],\,$ then dividing $f\,$ by $x$

yields  $\, f = x\, g + f_0\, $ for $\,f_0 = f(0)\,$ and $\,g\in D[x]$

Therefore $\,x\mid f\iff x\mid f_0 \iff  0 = f_0\,\ $ (by eval at $\,x=0)$

$\quad\ \begin{align}
{\rm thus}\ \ x\ {\rm is\  prime\ in }\ D[x] 
\ &\iff\  x\,\mid\, f\, g\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ x\mid f\ \ \ {\rm or}\,\ \ x\mid g\\[.3em]
&\iff \  0\!=\! f_0\: g_0\,\Rightarrow\, 0 =\!f_0\ \ {\rm or}\ \  0 = g_0\\[.3em]
&\iff \ D\ \text{is a domain}\ [\!\iff {\rm \color{#c00}{0\ is\ prime}\ in} \ D]
\end{align}$

Applying this to $D = K[y]$ yields that $\,x\,$ is prime in $K[y][x] \cong K[y,x]$

**Remark** $\ $ Thus the definition of $x$ is prime in $D[x],$ when evaluated at $x=0$, ends up being equivalent to $\,\color{#c00}{0\rm\ is\ prime}\,$ in $D$ (via $\,0\mid d\!\iff\! 0 = d),$ an equivalent form of $D$ is a domain.

Note $\,(x)$ prime $\iff x$ prime follows by comparing the definitions using "divides = contains" for principal ideals, i.e. $\ x\mid f\iff (x)\supseteq (f)\iff (x) \ni f$

When you learn about quotient rings and evaluation homs you will find it insightful to study how the above elementwise proof relates to the equivalent structural form.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate argument to show that $(x)$ is not maximal:

$$(x)\subsetneq (x,y)\subsetneq K[x,y]$$

Answer (score -1):

The answer of MatheiBoulomenos exploits the equivalence "$P$ prime $\iff$ $A/P$ domain" and is certainly correct.

But you can prove that $(x)$ is prime directly from the definition as follows.

Let $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ be two polynomials with 
$$
P(x,y)Q(x,y)\in(x).\qquad\qquad(*)
$$

Write $P(x,y)=p(y)+xP_1(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)=q(y)+xQ_1(x,y)$ separating the monomials that do not contain $x$.
Then
$$
P(x,y)Q(x,y)=p(y)q(y)+x[P_1(x,y)q(y)+Q_1(x,y)p(y)+xP_1(x,y)Q_1(x,y)]
$$
and the hypothesis $(*)$ implies that  $p(y)q(y)=0$. But since $K[y]$ is a domain this implies that, for instance, $p(y)=0$ which means that $P(x,y)\in(x)$.

Comment: @Thank you for your answer. That was the way that I was trying to prove it.

Comment: Someone didn't like it ... Would the downgrader care to explain the $-1$?

Comment: @Xam The downvotes are probably because the proof is incorrect, starting with "by hypothesis $pq = 0$". See my answer for a correct elementwise proof.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque yes. I didn't read carefully the above answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: why does the hypothesis $P\cdot Q\in(x)$ not imply $p\cdot q=0$?

Comment: I read "by hypothesis S" to mean S is true because it is a hypothesis. It appears what you meant is that S follows (easily) by (some) hypothesis. If you had given the details of that inference there would have been no ambiguity. And given the crucial role played by this inference, it is worth being being more explicit.

Comment: @BillDubuque Well, in order to prove that $(x)$ is prime I'm taking two elements whose product is in it. That's the running hypothesis. Because of that, every monomial in $P\cdot Q$ must contain an $x$ and that means $p\cdot q=0$. I slightly edited the answer to make this passage more clear.

Comment: @AdLibitum Of course *I* do know how to proceed, But it is not I that you need to convince, At *this level*, I think one should explicitly explain why $\,x\mid p(y)q(y)\,\Rightarrow\, p(y)q(y)=0.\,$ Some students struggle with that in this multivariate context. One easy way is explained in my answer, viz. $$\,x\mid f(x)\, \ {\rm in }\ R[x]\iff  0\mid f(0)\,\ {\rm in }\ R,\,\ \text{by eval at }\,x=0 $$